# Как получить строку из mysql содержащую условное значение(взятое изи параметра в url)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

У меня есть php который выводит всю таблицу на страницу, но мне нужно выводить строки который например содержат 123@gmail.com При этом я хочу чтобы этот параметр подставлялся из url с помощью $_GET['email']; подскажите ка это сделать?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 
$opt);
$stats = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY id DESC');
$stats->execute();
echo json_encode($stats->fetchAll());
exit;
```

С помощью поиска нашел вот такой способ, но не получилось

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 
$opt);
$stats = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM stats WHERE email LIKE \"123@gmail.com\"');
$stats->execute();
echo json_encode($stats->fetchAll());
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь привязкой параметров. В SQL-запросе напишите знак вопроса, а в аргументах метода [execute](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php) укажите фактическое значение из GET-параметра.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $opt);
$stats = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM stats WHERE email LIKE ?');
$stats->execute([ $_GET['email'] ]);
echo json_encode($stats->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Попробовал, но все равно выводит всю таблицу

Comment: Это странно. Учтите, что оператор LIKE означает соответствие шаблону, а не точное совпадение. Поэтому, например, сравнение с `'%'` всегда будет истинным. Вот посмотрите мой пример, работы с PDO - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yw4YWSqzn2/. Больше полезных примеров есть в документации, ссылку на которую я дал в ответе.